The link between SLOPE and the Benjamini-Hochberg procedure
Suppose we are performing $m$ tests which generates $m$ p-values $p_1 \leq \ldots \leq p_m$ (with the indexes ordered). The BH procedure is as follows:

For a given $\alpha$ (the desired FDR level), find the largest $k$ such that $p_k \leq \frac{k}{m}\alpha$.
Reject the null hypothesis $H_i$ for all $i\leq k$.

Now, I've been reading a bit about the Sorted L-One Penalized Estimation (SLOPE) model, which is based off this, but I'm struggling to see the exact connection. In the SLOPE paper, the BH procedure is described as follows (and this formulation is used to derive the SLOPE penalty sequences):
For a regression model $y = X\beta + z,$ with $z \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and orthogonal matrix $X^TX = I$, sort the entries of $\tilde{y} = X^Ty$ into $|y|_{(1)} \geq \ldots \geq |y|_{(m)}$ and reject all hypotheses $H_i$ for which $i\leq k_\text{BH}$ where
$$k_\text{BH} = \max\left\{k:
\frac{|\tilde{y}|_{(k)}}{\sigma} \geq \Phi^{(-1)}\left(1-\frac{k\alpha}{2m}\right)\right\}.$$
Now, I'm wondering what the connection is between these two and how the quantile value is used. I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact in SLOPE we are using $\tilde{y}$ instead of a p-value and we need to somehow convert it onto the same scale as a p-value comparison.

Your sense is essentially correct.
It helps to write out what $\tilde{y}$ means in this situation (Equation 1.1 of the cited paper) in which $m$ coefficients (in the $m \times 1$ vector $\beta$) are estimated by ordinary linear regression, with observed values $y$, orthogonal design matrix $X$, and errors $z$ having known variance $\sigma^2$:
$$\tilde{y} = X′y = X′X\beta + X′z = \beta + X′z.$$
That is an $m \times 1$ vector in which the elements are individual coefficients and each has a normal distribution with known variance $\sigma^2$.
The test on an individual coefficient estimate $\hat \beta_j$ is then a z-test evaluating $|\hat\beta_j|/\sigma$ against a standard normal distribution. in a two-sided test, the rejection region for the single null hypotheses $\beta_j=0$ at significance level $\alpha$ is then
$$ \frac{|\hat\beta_j|}{\sigma} \ge \Phi^{(-1)}\left(1-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right).$$
Analogous to the Benjamini-Hochberg (BH) FDR approach, the $\alpha/2$ term is sequentially corrected along the descending rank order $k$ of the $\beta$ values by $k/m$. That puts the highest penalty on the largest coefficient estimate, just like BH puts the highest penalty on the most significant (lowest) p-value.
The authors note, however, that the choice of penalty values in the SLOPE method "is neither equivalent to the step-up [BH] procedure described above nor to the step-down version." Think of the BH procedure as the inspiration for SLOPE, not how SLOPE is implemented.

In the section 'Adaptive penalization and multiple testing in orthogonal designs.' they introduce the method for the special case of an orthogonal design matrix.
In that case the parameter selection with the LASSO procedure is equivalent to imposing boundaries to the OLS regression parameters.
$$\hat{\beta}_j^{\text{lasso}} = 0 \quad \text{ if abs}(\hat{\beta}_j^{OLS}) \le \lambda_j /2$$
See for example How is the lasso orthogonal design case solution derived?
And these boundaries can be related to the critical values of the acceptance region in hypothesis testing.

The connection with the BH procedure is to use rejection/inclusion criteria by means of the penalty coefficients $\lambda_j$ that are different based on the order of the coefficient.
A difference with the BH procedure is that you don't get this

and reject all hypotheses $H_i$ for which $i\leq k_\text{BH}$

With the penalties $\lambda_j$ you get only individual comparisons. This can be explained with the image below adapted from the question How to deal with identical p-values with the Benjamini-Hochberg method for correcting for multiple testing

the image shows the ranking of the p-values and a blue line gives the boundary condition used for deciding on the hypotheses. With the BH procedure you will identify the 10-th p-value as the highest value below the line and you reject all of the ten hypotheses associated with the first ten p-values. Even the 1st, 6th and 7th p-values that are above the line.
The SLOPE/LASSO method is different in not including those 1st, 6th and 7th values based on the 10th value. It will select the parameters untill the first parameter that is above the line (so in the example zero parameters will be selected and the method has little effect, but in other cases you may get the advantage that more parameters are included).
In the geometrical view of Lasso it is like the square shaped boundary becomes more like a star.


To me the approach appears to be similar to the Holm-Bonferroni method where the ordered hypotheses are rejected one by one (with variable criteria for different orders) untill the first non-rejected hypothesis.

Excellent point about SLOPE perhaps being more closely analogous to Holm-Bonferroni than Benjamini-Hochberg (BH). The SLOPE paper notes that SLOPE isn't the same as BH; your answer illustrates that nicely. (+1)
